# How to click Captcha "click to verify" button with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, click

I'm trying to use XPath to click a "click to verify" captcha button and it is not working. It returns the error message:

> Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="1e505deed3832c02c96ca5abe70df9ab"]/div"}

Here's my code:

```
click_to_verify = wd.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="1e505deed3832c02c96ca5abe70df9ab"]/div')
click_to_verify.click()
```

I'm not worried yet about the captcha that will appear when I click the button. I just want to be able to click the button. Any suggestions?

Comment: this can be because you are trying to click the box before it appears or you are using a wrong xpath, try waiting till the box appears or check the xpath

Comment: @EzyGrip I am not running all cells in the kernel, I am repeatedly editing and running the cell with the click code while on the page with the click to verify button. Nothing I'm trying is working. I've tried different xpaths and css selector.

Comment: can u pls provide the URL or the HTML details

Comment: from your post id looks dynamic one

Comment: there is something wrong with your x-path sometimes x-path's must be more specific or in other types of formats, please provide the target URL that we can give you a solution

Answer (score 0):

I would probably say that the captcha you want to click is in iframe. It is very common design to put captcha in an iframe. If it's in iframe you would need to switch the focus of web driver like this :

```
wait = WebDriverWait(wd, 10)
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "iframe xpath")))
click_to_verify = wd.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="1e505deed3832c02c96ca5abe70df9ab"]/div')
click_to_verify.click()
```

and I would not recommend you to use `1e505deed3832c02c96ca5abe70df9ab` in **xpath**, since it may change every time you execute your script .

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score 0):

So in the end I just decided to install pyautogui and use it to move the mouse to the specific part of the screen that needed to be clicked. Maybe not the most elegant solution but it worked for me in this situation.

```
import pyautogui

pyautogui.click(600, 525)
```